# Predual of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, analytic-functions, preduals

Is the predual of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ contained in the maximal ideal space of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$?

Comment: The maximal ideal space lies in the dual unit sphere, so it doesn't contain any vector space whatsoever.

Comment: I think that you will find that this is a botched edit.  My conjecture is that the intended query was whether the spectrum is containED in the predual--also false.